# Handling abandoned/disconnected Sockets

Tags: .net, sockets

If i have 100 devices connected to a socket server and the power goes out on the clients. When the power is reconnected I will get 100 new client socket connections.

The server will now have 200 socket connections. 100 of which are abandoned.

Do I need to detect/handle/close these abandoned connections or will .net/windows detect this and clear it up in the background?

Answer (score 0):

the connections will be closed (assuming TCP)

You will know that those connections are dead. Exactly how depends on your coding. Is async you will receive an endreceive event. If sync your next read or write fail.

You already have code for dealing with unusual end of connection (don't you) , in this case you just get a lot of those at once

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe is one of the purposes of the TCP "KeepAlive" setting.  Because the TCP protocol generally doesn't require either party to say anything except when it has reason to believe that it knows something about the connection that the other party doesn't, connections where neither party has had anything to say since its last data packet was acknowledged don't generate any traffic.  It is thus impossible to distinguish a device which has ceased to exist from one which is alive and connected but simply doesn't have anything it wants to say.

If a party to a connection has "KeepAlive" set, then if a certain length of time (typically a few minutes) elapses without any traffic in either direction, that party will pretend to "forget" that it had received an acknowledgment for the last byte it sent and will consequently resend that byte.  If the other party to the connection is still alive, it will see the retransmission and recognize it as such (ignoring the data therein), but it will send an acknowledgment on the premise that the other side might have missed the earlier acknowledgment, and even if the other side did see the earlier acknowledgment retransmitting it will be harmless.  If the other party to the connection does exist, but knows nothing of the connection, it will immediately send a "reset" packet to indicate that, thus killing the connection.  If the other party to the connection doesn't exist, the retransmitted byte will never get acknowledged; after repeated attempts to resend that byte, the party trying to send it will eventually give up and kill the connection.

Enabling KeepAlive will ensure that if one side of a connection disappears, the other side will eventually find out about it.  KeepAlive times are generally fairly long (minutes), and the KeepAlive time merely sets the point when one party will *start* looking for the other.  If the other party simply disappears, it may take another minute or so for the system to decide the other party is well and truly gone.  Still, discovering the other party's disappearance after a few minutes is often better than never finding out at all.